# How to use arguments from constructor to call a constructor of another class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initialization

I have a question. I want to call a constructor of "gameWindow" from the class "Game". The problem is that if I call it from the constructor it is initialising as a local variable (example A), if I define it in as a private member - I can not use arguments of a constructor. How can I make gamewindowObj as a member from a constructor?

//example А

```
class Game{
public:
    Game(int inWidth, int inHeight, char const * Intitle);
};

Game::Game(int inWidth, int inHeight, char const * Intitle){
    gameWindow gamewindowObj=gameWindow(inWidth, inHeight, Intitle);
}
```

//example В

```
class Game{
public:
    Game(int inWidth, int inHeight, char const * Intitle);
private:
    gameWindow gamewindowObj=gameWindow(inWidth, inHeight, Intitle);
};
Game::Game(int inWidth, int inHeight, char const * Intitle){}
```

Comment: use the constructors initializer list: `Game(int inWidth,....) : gamewindowObj(inWidht,...) {}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `gamewindowObj` to be a data member and be initialized by the constructor's arguments, you can use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), e.g.

```
class Game{
public:
    Game(int inWidth, int inHeight, char const * Intitle);
private:
    gameWindow gamewindowObj;
};

Game::Game(int inWidth, int inHeight, char const * Intitle) 
    : gamewindowObj(inWidth, inHeight, Intitle) {
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @songyuanyao

Comment: Also, to the OP.  It's sometimes worth writing a function which can be used to initialize `gameWindow` if it is not just a matter of reusing arguments.  `gameWindow&& initGameWindow(int arg1, int arg2) {/*complex stuff*/}`